# React navigation hook not working as expected in Class component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use react-navigation to move between two pages, Selecttype.js and doctorlogin.js in which Selecttype.js is the `initialRouteName` and has a button that will redirect to doctorlogin.js when someone clicks it. The `initialRoute` is loading fine but I can't access doctorlogin.js using the `onclick()` event.

**App.js: (Router)**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Selecttype from './components/selecttype'
import DoctorLogin from './components/doctorlogin'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Selecttype">
        <Stack.Screen name="Selecttype" component={Selecttype} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dlogin" component={DoctorLogin} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Selecttype.js: (Initial Route)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default class Selecttype extends React.Component { 

  doctorlogin(){
   var navigation = useNavigation();
   navigation.navigate('Dlogin')
}

  patientlogin(){
   var navigation = useNavigation();
   navigation.navigate('Plogin')
}

  render(){
  return (<>
   <Text style={{fontSize: 24, fontWeight: "bold", textAlign: "center", position: "relative", top: 159}}>Select who you are:</Text>
   <View style={styles.selectbtnsa}>
   <Button title="Doctor" onPress={this.doctorlogin}/>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.selectbtnsb}>
   <Button title="Patient" onPress={this.patientlogin}/>
   </View>
  </>);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   selectbtnsa: {
      position: "relative",
      top: 189,
      borderRadius: 20,
      borderColor: "black",
   },
   selectbtnsb: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 199,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
   },
});
```

**Doctorlogin.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import '../configs/firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default class Doctorlogin extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            code: "",
        }
        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
        this.handleCode = this.handleCode.bind(this);
    }

    dlogin = () => {
        return firebase.database().ref(this.state.name).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
          var dcode = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().code)
          
          if(dcode === this.state.code){
            const navigation = useNavigation();
            navigation.navigate('Dhome')
        }else{
              alert("You entered the wrong code")
          }    
        });
    }
    
    handleName(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleCode(e) {
        this.setState({
            code: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render(){
    return(<>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 24, fontWeight: "bold", textAlign: "center", position: "relative", top: 159}}>Doctor Login:</Text>
   <View style={styles.selectbtnsa}>
   <TextInput placeholder=" Enter your Name..." style={{height: 30}} onChange={this.handleName}/>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.selectbtnsb}>
   <TextInput placeholder=" Enter your 8-digit code..." style={{height: 30}} onChange={this.handleCode}/>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.selectbtnsc}>
   <Button title="Login" onPress={this.dlogin}/>
   </View> 
        </>)
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   selectbtnsa: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 189,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: "black",
 },
 selectbtnsb: {
  position: "relative",
  top: 199,
  borderRadius: 10,
  borderColor: "black",
 },
 selectbtnsc: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 209,
    left: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
},
});
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: You cannot use hooks in class components.

Comment: @SagarShakya can you please explain it in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can't be used inside a class component as explain in Hooks FAQ on reactjs.org

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

Link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both